# Can't center nested grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing a mobile first approach to making my website. The whole website is inside one main grid. I also want to have other small grids that will act as links to other html pages. I made a sample nested grid but cannot center it. I want the `<a>` element with the class `project_prev` to be centered within the body with id `main-grid`. It's at the very bottom of the HTML file, I included the previous stuff just in case. Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body id="main-grid">
    <h1 id="header"></h1>
    <img id="header_img" src=""></img>
    <section id="about_blk" class="blk">
        <h2>About</h2>
        <p></p>
    </section>
    <button id="reveal_btn" onclick="reveal()">More</button>
    <section id="more_blk">
        <section id="skills_blk" class="blk">
            <h2>Skills</h2>
            <ul><b></b>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
            <br>
            <ul><b></b>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <section id="projects_blk" class="blk">
            <h2>Projects</h2>
            <a class="project_prev" href="color_schemes.html">
                <div class="project_top">
                    <h3>Color Theory</h3>
                </div>
                <p>This interactive page teaches you the basics of color theory.</p>
            </a>
        </section>
        <section id="contact_blk" class="blk">
            <h2></h2>
            <p></p>
        </section>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: var(--text-color);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

:root {
    --text-color: #0E151E;
    --link-color: #75CDD9;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#main-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 60px 150px repeat(4, auto);
    grid-template-columns: 96%;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    justify-content: center;
}

#header {
    grid-row: 1/2;
    grid-column: 1/3;
    place-self: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#header_img {
    grid-row: 2/3;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    height: 150px;
    place-self: center;
    border-radius: 75px;
    border: 3px solid var(--text-color);
}

#about_blk {
    grid-row: 3/4;
    grid-column: 1/2;
}

#more_blk {
    grid-row: 4/7;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    display: none;
}

#reveal_btn {
    grid-row: 7/8;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid var(--text-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    justify-self: center;
    transition: 200ms linear 100ms;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#reveal_btn:hover {
    background-color: var(--text-color);
    color: #fff;
}

#skills_blk {
    grid-row: 4/5;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

#projects_blk {
    grid-row: 5/6;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

#contact_blk {
    text-align: center;
    grid-row: 6/7;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

#insta_link {
    grid-row: 2/3;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    place-self: center;
}

.blk {
    /*Style for the grid blocks*/
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.blk h2,
ul, p{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    color: var(--link-color);
}

.project_prev {
    justify-self: center;
    width: 350px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 60px 140px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    border: 2px solid var(--text-color);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.project_prev:hover {
    scale: 1.01;
}

.project_top {
    justify-self: center;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) ), url();
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.project_top h3 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function reveal() {
    var more_blk = document.getElementById("more_blk");
    var visible = more_blk.style.display;
    var button = document.getElementById("reveal_btn");

    if (visible === "inline-block") {
        more_blk.style.display = "none";
        button.textContent = "More";
    } else {
        more_blk.style.display = "inline-block";
        button.textContent = "Less";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily center items with flex and `align-items: center`

I added the following to your css to center everything inside the `<section id="projects_blk" class="blk">`

```css
#projects_blk {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**Do not just copy this code** since you should avoid using the ID selector in css, I just did it like this for demonstration.

Full code:

```js
function reveal() {
    var more_blk = document.getElementById("more_blk");
    var visible = more_blk.style.display;
    var button = document.getElementById("reveal_btn");

    if (visible === "inline-block") {
        more_blk.style.display = "none";
        button.textContent = "More";
    } else {
        more_blk.style.display = "inline-block";
        button.textContent = "Less";
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: var(--text-color);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

:root {
    --text-color: #0E151E;
    --link-color: #75CDD9;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#main-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 60px 150px repeat(4, auto);
    grid-template-columns: 96%;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    justify-content: center;
}

#header {
    grid-row: 1/2;
    grid-column: 1/3;
    place-self: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#header_img {
    grid-row: 2/3;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    height: 150px;
    place-self: center;
    border-radius: 75px;
    border: 3px solid var(--text-color);
}

#about_blk {
    grid-row: 3/4;
    grid-column: 1/2;
}

#more_blk {
    grid-row: 4/7;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    display: none;
}

#reveal_btn {
    grid-row: 7/8;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid var(--text-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    justify-self: center;
    transition: 200ms linear 100ms;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#reveal_btn:hover {
    background-color: var(--text-color);
    color: #fff;
}

#skills_blk {
    grid-row: 4/5;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

#projects_blk {
    grid-row: 5/6;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

#contact_blk {
    text-align: center;
    grid-row: 6/7;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

#insta_link {
    grid-row: 2/3;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    place-self: center;
}

.blk {
    /*Style for the grid blocks*/
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.blk h2,
ul, p{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    color: var(--link-color);
}

.project_prev {
    justify-self: center;
    width: 350px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 60px 140px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    border: 2px solid var(--text-color);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.project_prev:hover {
    scale: 1.01;
}

.project_top {
    justify-self: center;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) ), url();
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.project_top h3 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

#projects_blk {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body id="main-grid">
    <h1 id="header"></h1>
    <img id="header_img" src="" />
    <section id="about_blk" class="blk">
      <h2>About</h2>
      <p></p>
    </section>
    <button id="reveal_btn" onclick="reveal()">More</button>
    <section id="more_blk">
      <section id="skills_blk" class="blk">
        <h2>Skills</h2>
        <ul><b></b>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <ul><b></b>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <section id="projects_blk" class="blk">
        <h2>Projects</h2>
        <a class="project_prev" href="color_schemes.html">
          <div class="project_top">
            <h3>Color Theory</h3>
          </div>
          <p>This interactive page teaches you the basics of color theory.</p>
        </a>
      </section>
      <section id="contact_blk" class="blk">
        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>
      </section>
    </section>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. I'll definitely be using this in the future!

Comment: _"...since you should avoid using the ID selector in css..."_   But why should I? ID selectors seem to work fine for me every time.

Comment: It's just a good practise to avoid using the ID selector, in a case like this you may want to apply this style to some other elements so using a class is better [see this article](https://dev.to/clairecodes/reasons-not-to-use-ids-in-css-4ni4)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this. I just use IDs because it makes Javascript slightly easier